# Como pegar um template que está em outro app no Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Fala galera, tudo bem com vocês? Então pessoal to começando agora a programar em Django estou realmente gostando, só que surgiu uma dúvida, queria saber se tem como deixar o template

> base.html

como "Universal" o que eu quero dizer é que não quero ficar criando diversas vezes a base.html em cada app que eu criar, para ficar mais claro vou colocar um print aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A seta verde é a principal, ou seja, é da onde eu quero herdar a base mas como eu não estava conseguindo acabei por fazer a da seta vermelha mas isso não é funcional pois se eu quiser adicionar um link no menu por exemplo terei que mexer na base.html de cada app e isso acaba fazendo com que eu perca tempo.

Bem se não ficou claro, comente para mim que tentarei explicar de outra forma.
Desde já agradeço :).

PS: Já tentei colocar na pasta static e não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Maurício!

Recomendo você dar uma olhada em herança de template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Acredito que seja de fácil entendimento. Como você já criou o base.html, irá facilitar o trabalho. Mas praticamente você cria um bloco de conteúdo dentro do seu base.html e nos outros templates você coloca todo o conteúdo dentro desses blocos.

Comment: Obrigado por responder Douglas, então cara eu já tinha dado uma olhada nisso e realmente funciona, porém quando vou dar extends na base.html de outra app ele o não funciona.

Comment: eu queria um modo de estender um template de outra app saca

Comment: No template dos outros apps tente fazer o seguinte: {% extends "app_config/base.html" %}. Na teoria era pra funcionar, pois o Django irá buscar esse .html diretamente na pasta templates do app_config.

Comment: Funcionou cara, eu realmente não tinha pensado desse forma... fiquei preso no jeito que nos chegamos em um arquivo de outra pasta (../../) voltando os diretorios, enfim consegui, muito obrigado mesmo cara, poderia colocar como resposta isso

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha dado certo, Maurício. Bons estudos!

Comment: Mauricio: se a resposta _não resolveu_ o seu problema, _não_ marque como aceita (o check verde) - você pode dar um upvote se quiser. Mas me parece que a pergunta não foi respondida apropriadamente, só que como há uma resposta aceita, ninguém mais vai se interessar em responder.

Answer (score 0):

É só herdar de "base.html" em outro app, sem fazer mais nada.

Todas as pastas de "template" de todos os apps do django são consolidadas num espaço de nomes único. Em outras palavras - na hora de importar, extender ou renderizar templates - seja puxando eles de dentro de um template, seja do código, o django expõe *todos* os arquivos de template em *todos* os apps instalados.

Então se você tem um app 'mestre' onde vai deixar o template 'base.html' que você quer re-utilizar, pode fazer:

```
/
/mestre/
/mestre/templates
/mestre/templates/base.html
/app1
/app1/templates
/app1/templates/pagina_do_app1.html
```

e dentro do arquivo `pagina_do_app1.html` pode usar tranquilamente `{% extends 'base.html' %}` que ele vai puxar o template no arquivo com esse nome, mesmo estando no outro app. (Apenas certifique-se de que o outro app está instalado no `installed_apps` do `settings` do seu projeto de django)

A única recomendação se você vai usar templates entre projetos diferentes, é adicionar uma pasta a mais, dentro da pasta de templates, com o nome do app - e colocar os templates de cada app lá dentro. Isso vai evitar conflitos. Por exemplo, vamos supor que você adicione uma extensão do django que *também* tenha um template `base.html` - aí qual base.html ele vai puxar, se o seu, ou o dessa extensão, é basicamente sorte (depende da ordem no "installed_apps", acho) )

Então, pra evitar isso, crie um nível a mais de diretórios de forma que o seu template agora seja puxado como `{% extends`mestre/base.html`%}`:

```
/
/mestre/
/mestre/templates
/mestre/templates/mestre/
/mestre/templates/mestre/base.html
/app1
/app1/templates
/app1/templates/app1
/app1/templates/app1/pagina_do_app1.html
```

(e no seu código Python, claro, usar os templates do app1 como `render(request, "app1/pagina_do_app1.html", ...)` )